# How to make reactive window parameters in Vue.js | window.innerWidth is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have the trouble that i have to do some calculations based on the innerWidth of the window but whenever i change my window width my computed property doesnt get triggered, how do i make it work?

Here is my code simplyfied:

```
var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#elment',
   computed: {
      calculation: function(){
         console.log(window.innerWidth)
         return window.innerWidth;
      }
   }
})
```

The console prints me the width just on the begin 1x.
How do i make this reactive?
My alternative way was to add an event listener to the body in the mounted hook and to do my calculations there.

Comment: Your idea in adding an event listener to the body when mounted, is a correct one. But if you have many codes, which concern about window.innerWidth, you may use mixins, to share the bit of code you want for multiple components

Comment: @CHANist i guess the mounted hook is the way to go because its just 1 piece of code block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this moment, there’s no way in VueJS to natively “watch” a window property or making it reactive.

Let's just rewind some concepts of `EventBus` in Vue. Vue is capable of creating another truly independent & reactive Vue Instance that is decoupled from the main instance. We often do this when starting a new Vue app or creating an EventBus.

So the solution for this is to create a “WindowInstanceMap”. Create a reactive `innerWidth` data and an event listener that silently “mutates” it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const WindowInstanceMap = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      innerWidth: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    const self = this;
    window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
      self.innerWidth = window.innerWidth
    })
  },
})

export default WindowInstanceMap
```

With this, we have created a clone of the window interface and innerWidth is reactive. Now let’s try to use it somewhere.
Let’s import this in `App.js` first to “inititalize” the component:

```
// App.js
import WindowInstanceMap from './WindowInstanceMap.js'
```

This will trigger the `create()` lifecycle of `WindowInstanceMap` and register the resize event listener to window.

Now in my components. All we need to do is map it to a `computed` prop.

```
// SomeComponent.vue
import WindowInstanceMap from './WindowInstanceMap.js'
export default {
  computed: {
    innerWidth () { return WindowInstanceMap.innerWidth }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you i done it like you in the `created` lifecycle and it works fine now

Comment: there is 1 mistake i found out. `this` in `this.innerWidth` is reffered to the global `window` instead of the vue instance, so i changed `this.innerWidth` to `WindowInstanceMap.innerWidth`

Comment: Updated, better to save context in a variable.